# ASP.NET session id - unique across servers

Tags: asp.net, session, unique

Is session id repeatable across servers for in-proc session? For example we are using 2 IIS servers - is there any chance that the IIS servers could create the same session id? We are using NLB servers and sticky session.

Answer (score 0):

[Look into storing the session state in a database](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3595766/Storing-Session-State-in-a-SQL-Server-Database.htm) which can be shared between multiple servers.